# How can i divide a web page into 2 sections and 2nd section containing 4 sections - Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


</head>

<body class="line">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="line">
      <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:#F5F5DC;">
        First column
      </div>

      <div id=second class="col-md-9" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <div id=firstleft class="col-md-6" style="background-color:blue;">First</div>
        <div id=firstright class="col-md-6" style="background-color:red;">Second</div>
        <div id=secondleft class="col-md-6" style="background-color:yellow;">Third</div>
        <div id=secondright class="col-md-6" style="background-color:green;">Fourth</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div </body>

</html>
```

I am new to web development but I want to redesign and develop a homepage that looks like the image attached.

I have tried finding the solution using bootstrap grid. But I am not getting the correct display.

Expected Result should be

[image: Expected Result]

Actual Result that I am getting

[image: Actual Result]

I have created the HTML file, but confused on how to write a css file by which I can achieve my expected results.

Comment: i don't understand. what exactly you want to achieve ? ( also please take another look at your HTML structure . you should use `row` not `line` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go... Doing with flex box is easy..

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
html,body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  color:#fff;
}
.content-wrap {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
}
.child {
  display: flex; 
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  flex-basis: 50%;  
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
}
.child1{
  background-color:#ccc;
}
.child2{
  background-color:#333;
}
.child3{
  background-color:#999;
}
.child4{
  background-color:#666;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar"> checkboxes</div>
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <div class="child child1"></div>
      <div class="child child2"></div>
      <div class="child child3"></div>
      <div class="child child4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot Chetan. The code you gave is working perfectly fine.

Comment: You are welcome @Ravikiran  Please accept the answer if that is what you needed

Comment: Hey Chetan!! What I found is it works perfectly fine in Mozilla and Chrome, but the boxes appear one below the other if I open in Internet Explorer (Currently 11 is present on my machine). Do I also need to add something so that it will be cross browser compatible.

Comment: just use -ms- prefix for the flexbox items to have it work in IE. btw it doesnt work on IE9 or below

Comment: I use IE 11 and I think whatever you have given in CSS is perfectly fine because as per below link we should avoid using -ms- for IE11

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265027%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I tried adding -ms- to properties like (display: -ms-flex; -ms-flex-direction etc  ) but still the problem exists. Thanks a ton for your responses Chetan :)

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand. what exactly you want to achieve ? ( also please take another look at your HTML structure . you should use row not line )

i guess you want something like this ? use `row-eq-height` to have equal height columns ( it uses flexbox )

see snippet below or [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/33737/)

```css
.col-sm-6 {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:#F5F5DC;">
      First column
    </div>

    <div id=second class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="background-color:yellow;">
      <div class="row row_inner">


        <div id=firstleft class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background-color:blue;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nullam eros posuere quam, non ipsum ornare vehicula. In integer, ac tempus aenean lorem nec amet ac, non blandit class, eget odio eu, mollis mauris massa. In augue erat convallis, morbi lectus lobortis tempor in lorem.
          Dis et morbi consectetuer non, tempor pretium. Leo dolor erat orci, lobortis adipisicing scelerisque integer diam lorem, tempus non, dolor libero vivamus velit. Viverra ipsum quam id in arcu, ligula tortor laoreet fermentum sit ipsum. Erat dapibus
          nulla justo vitae, feugiat nullam felis sollicitudin, dolor wisi mauris, tristique tempus nunc tristique. Velit non, duis auctor a. Ipsum pede maecenas vestibulum id ornare, ac facilisi wisi maecenas sem ultrices, non pede cupiditate mollis
          lorem condimentum, suscipit integer etiam mauris amet. Magna rutrum cras, tincidunt lacus ut, lectus donec, scelerisque mauris elementum non ac. Morbi cursus tortor vehicula molestiae metus ipsum.</div>
        <div id=firstright class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background-color:red;">Second</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row_inner">
        <div id=secondleft class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background-color:yellow;">Third</div>
        <div id=secondright class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background-color:green;">Fourth</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i added also `sm` and `xs` classes for example purposes only

Answer (score 0):

An example using the unit `vh` for height... Go full screen for the effect you described.

```css
.left {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.blocks {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid page">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 left" style="background-color:#F5F5DC;">
        First column
      </div>

      <div id="second" class="col-md-9" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <div class="row">


          <div id="firstleft" class="col-md-6 blocks" style="background-color:blue;">
            Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br>Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br>

          </div>
          <div id="firstright" class="col-md-6 blocks" style="background-color:red;">
            Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br>Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br>
          </div>
          <div id="secondleft" class="col-md-6 blocks" style="background-color:yellow;">
            Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br>Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br>
          </div>
          <div id="secondright" class="col-md-6 blocks" style="background-color:green;">
            Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br>Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br> Content
            <br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.row
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar
{
    padding-bottom: 1005px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
    background-color: #a5a5a5;
}
.col-md-6 
{
    height: 300px;
}
.grid1, .grid4 
{
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
.grid2, .grid3 
{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">Sidebar</div>
        <div class="col-md-10 content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 grid1">1st scrollable grid</div>
                <div class="col-md-6 grid2">2st scrollable grid</div>
                <div class="col-md-6 grid3">3st scrollable grid</div>
                <div class="col-md-6 grid4">4st scrollable grid</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]